# Connect multiple vms to external network

Tags: virtualbox

Currently, I have 2 VM's(Ubuntu) running on my mac machine. Now, I need following things to happen -

1. VM's needs to communicate with each other.
2. VM's needs to communicate external as well(eg: able to ping google.com)

I'm able to do either one of these but could not get both working.

For VM's to communicate each other, I setup a host only adapter which assigns a ip for each vm's and its able to communicate but this cuts the communication to the external work.

If I setup to NAT, the VM's are able to talk externally but not within each other.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There are two types of NAT networking for VirtualBox, the second called "NAT Network" (`natnetwork`) is experimental but is supposed to allow VMs to talk to each other as well as the network (unlike base NAT).

Comment: Thanks ..it worked...

Comment: I see it assigned internal ipaddress to both of my machines(starting with 10.2.15.*)..From my understanding anything that starts with 10 is a internal ip address..but how im able to ping other vm without any issues? Don't i need a external ipaddress to ping a machine?

Comment: You won't be able to ping the VMs  from the general internet, but you should be able to ping from your internal machine. The NATing should also allow you to ping internet machines from your VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of networks with NAT in their name in VirtualBox. The base one, "NAT", does not allow VMs to see each other even though it allows contact to the external network.

The newer, experimental one called "NAT Network" or NAT Networking Service" (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service) allows both internal and external communication much like machines connected to a home router (to paraphrase the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to NAT mode, you can also get what you want by using the bridged network mode. It will allow your host and VMs to communicate each other as if they are all connected in the same network, and if your host is connected to the internet then your VMs are connected to the internet as well.